# Facebook Graph API not returning some conversations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api to get all the conversations of a facebook page using the page access token. Everything is working fine. However , in some cases the graph api is not returning all the conversations. The conversation is present in the inbox when I go and check it but the graph api is not returning the same. How could this be happening? I googled a lot about this , but to no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am using graph api explorer to pull the conversations using the conversations endpoint.

Comment: i believe you can only get unread inbox items, not 100% sure though. just something you could test.

Comment: Tnx for the reply....but I am getting other read inbox items.